# Collection-less model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

Consider following Model and View. I wonder why following indicated line does not work?

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    app.CurrentUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('.avatar-container'),
        template: ux.template('.avatar-container-hbs'),

        initialize: function () {
            this.model = new app.User();
            this.model.fetch();
            x=this.model;
            //these two lines output expected values.
            console.log(this.model);
            console.log(this.model.toJSON());
            this.render();
        },


        // Re-render the titles of the post item.
        render: function () {
        //this does not work! (empty)
             this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
})();
```

Model:

```
var app = app || {};

(function () {
    'use strict';

    app.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'api/user.php'
    });
})();
```

Comment: You need to call your `render` method in success handler of `fetch`.

Comment: @NiranjanBorawake Do you mean: `this.model.fetch().done((function () {
                this.render();
            }));` I tried it. But it has scope problem. Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Please check below code and update `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your view's initialize method as below :

```
initialize : function() {
        var self = this;
        this.model = new app.User();
        this.model.fetch({
            success : function(model, response, options) {
                self.render();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @PHPst How do you instantiate view?

Comment: `new app.CurrentUserView();`

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Are you sure you have added `var self = this;` at the start of `initialize` function? I think a jsfiddle would help both of us :)

Comment: I wonder why in todo sample application of backbone render is not placed inside fetch function, and yet it works? `initialize: function() {
  this.collection = new app.Library();
  this.collection.fetch();
  this.render();`

Comment: Could you please provide link to this sample application? When you do `this.collection.fetch()` or `this.model.fetch()` an AJAX `GET` request is sent to the server @ the `url` mentioned while declaring `Collection` or `Model`. Since it is an asynchronous request, you have to do your stuff in its success handler. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/blob/gh-pages/exercise-2/site/js/views/library.js

Comment: Took some time to find it. Here is the reason, in this example when the application starts, the Library View is passed sample data (books array) which is then used to initialize Library collection and so **NO** server call is involved. Go thorough [link] (https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone-fundamentals/blob/gh-pages/chapters/05-exercise-2.md)